# How to handle UTF8 string from Pythons imaplib

Tags: python, utf-8, imaplib

Python imaplib sometimes returns strings that looks like this:

```
=?utf-8?Q?Repertuar_wydarze=C5=84_z_woj._Dolno=C5=9Bl=C4=85skie?=
```

What is the name for this notation?

How can I decode (or should I say encode?) it to UTF8?

Answer (score 3):

**In short:**

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> msg = decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?Repertuar_wydarze=C5=84_z_woj._Dolno=C5=9Bl=C4=85skie?=')[0][0].decode('utf-8')
>>> msg
'Repertuar wydarze\u0144 z woj. Dolno\u015bl\u0105skie'
```

My computer doesn't show the polish characters, but they should appear in yours (locales etc.)

---

**Explained:**

Use the `email.header` decoder:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> value = decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?Repertuar_wydarze=C5=84_z_woj._Dolno=C5=9Bl=C4=85skie?=')
>>> value
[(b'Repertuar wydarze\xc5\x84 z woj. Dolno\xc5\x9bl\xc4\x85skie', 'utf-8')]
```

That will return a list with the decoded header, usually containing one tuple with the decoded message and the encoding detected (sometimes more than one pair).

```
>>> msg, encoding = decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?Repertuar_wydarze=C5=84_z_woj._Dolno=C5=9Bl=C4=85skie?=')[0]
>>> msg
b'Repertuar wydarze\xc5\x84 z woj. Dolno\xc5\x9bl\xc4\x85skie'
>>> encoding
'utf-8'
```

And finally, if you want `msg` as a normal utf-8 string, use the bytes `decode` method:

```
>>> msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
>>> msg
'Repertuar wydarze\u0144 z woj. Dolno\u015bl\u0105skie'
```

Comment: thank you! Can I decode complete header, or should I do it field by field?

Comment: `decode_header` should return all the decoded messages. but try it to see if it gives you the wanted result

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the bytes decoder instead , here is an example:

`result, data = imapSession.uid('search', None, "ALL")`  #search and return uids
 `latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]`  #data[] is a list, using split() to separate them by space and getting the latest one by [-1]

`result, data = imapSession.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(BODY.PEEK[])')`

`raw_email = data[0][1].decode("utf-8")` #using utf-8 decoder`